# How to open mp4 with php

Tags: php

but it doesn't show the video.

```
<?php
    $file = $_GET['id'];
    header ("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    $mimetype = "video/mp4";
    header('Content-Type: '.$mimetype);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header ('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$file.';');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    readfile(realpath($file));
    exit;
?>
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: **Danger**! You are allowing anyone who can make an HTTP request to it to read **any** file on your server! Sanitise `$_GET`!

Comment: "but it doesn't show the video" — What is **it**?

Answer (score -1):

To show the video from your server, you'll need to add html5 [video](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) tag or `embed`

PHP FILE (`video.php`)

```
$file = $_GET["id"]; //'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4';
readfile($file);
```

HTML5 (`showVideo.php`)

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="video.php">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```